# Which type of gradient decent is used in neuralnet package of R?

Tags: r, neural-network, gradient-descent

As far as I understand, there are different types of gradient decent methods to update the weights of a neural network.

In the stochasic gradient decent for example the weights are updated after evaluating the the error for each example of the training dataset.

On the other hand, the batch gradient decent evaluates the error of a batch of training examples (more then just one) to update the weights.

Does anyone know which method is implemented in the neuralnet package of R? If it's the batch gradient decent what is the batchsize? And how am I able to control it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`neuralnet` by default uses an algorithm called [resilient backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rprop), which is a very special  gradient descent algorithm, because only the sign, not the magnitude of gradient is used.  Alternatively, back-propagation can be used when specifying the parameter `algorithm`.

In either case, I believe the optimization is not batched, or at least not something you have control over.